# how can i close files after open them in a function in c++

Tags: c++, hash, io

I work on using extensible hash to find the query FASTER.
my code is this steps:
1)read the main text file ( hudge file 4 GiB)
the file is some thing like this :

```
12435 alex romero
13452 jack robert
13485 marya car
45132 gun tribble
...
```

the user want to know that for example the key 12435 is related to what ?(answer:alex romero)

2)create a hash table for the keys in the file (i means 12435,13452,13485,...)
and i save this tables dynamically in hard disk in some text files named:0.txt,1.txt,2.txt and ....

3)when the user get query to the program then the program must calculate the hash function on its value and find the file that must be read then it is faster to find the result.

i have a function:

```
#define LIMIT 7
void writeInFile(int key , const char* charPos ){
    int remainder = key%(LIMIT*LIMIT);

    string myFileName;
    ostringstream convert;
    convert << remainder ;

    myFileName = convert.str();
    myFileName += ".txt";

    FILE *my_file;
    my_file = fopen(myFileName.c_str() ,"a");

    fputs("\n" ,my_file);
    fputs(charPos , my_file);
    //fclose(my_file);
}
```

i wondered that when i use `fclose` then the speed of the program will reduced !!!
then i dont use it at the end of the function but a problem that is when i use this function many times i can't close them then i cant get access to the files.
i want to create a "list" of FILEs that i can send refrence of them to the function like: `FILE &* myFiles[]` or `FILE &** myFiles` as 3th parameter that function gets...
but i see the errors .i dont know how is its syntax of this.i means some syntax like:

```
void writeInFile(int key , const char* charPos , FILE &*myFiles[] ) // this makes error
```

the other method that i think is that can i close those files that now I can't access to them ? or can i change my code that cause this ?

update:this is my full code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <limits>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

#define LIMIT 7

using namespace std;

void writeInFile(int key , const char* charPos ){
    int remainder = key%(LIMIT*LIMIT);

    string myFileName;
    ostringstream convert;
    convert << remainder ;

    myFileName = convert.str();
    myFileName += ".txt";

    FILE *my_file;
    my_file = fopen(myFileName.c_str() ,"a");

    fputs("\n" ,my_file);
    fputs(charPos ,my_file);
    //fclose(my_file);

}

int main(){
    string fileName;
    cout << "hello, please inter your file destination : " ;
    cin >> fileName;
    ifstream myFile ;
    myFile.open(fileName.c_str() ,ifstream::in |ifstream::binary);
    cout << "building the hash,please wait";
    string havij;//:D this is an unusable variable in this section :))
    int current;
    int index;
    int isCout=0;
    char buffer [10];

    //FILE *my_file[49];
    while(!myFile.eof()){

        cout << isCout << endl;
        isCout++;
        index = myFile.tellg();


        itoa(index , buffer ,10);
        //cout << buffer << endl;
        myFile >> current;
        writeInFile(current ,buffer);
        getline(myFile,havij);
    }
    myFile.close();
    fstream test;
    //for(int i =0 ; i<LIMIT*LIMIT-1 ; i++){
    //  fclose(my_file[i]);
    //}
    cout << endl << "static extensible hash structure builded please inter your query : " ;
    int query;
    cin >> query;
    int remainder = query%(LIMIT*LIMIT);

    string myFileName;
    ostringstream convert;
    convert << remainder ;

    myFileName = convert.str();
    myFileName += ".txt";

    ifstream myFile2;
    //myFile2 is now the files that create by program like : 12.txt ,25.txt ,....
    myFile2.open(myFileName.c_str() , ifstream::in | ifstream::binary);
    ifstream mainFile;
    mainFile.open(fileName.c_str(), ifstream::in | ifstream::binary);
    int position;
    string wanted;
    int tester;
    while(!myFile2.eof()){
        myFile2 >> position;

        mainFile.seekg(position ,ios::beg);
        mainFile >> tester;
        if (tester == query ){
            getline(mainFile ,wanted);
            cout << "the result of the key " << tester << " is  " << wanted << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Always close when you are done with them, in the scope they were created in. Period. Don't pre-optimize.

Comment: Why are you mixing C++ with C? Seems rather odd IMHO

Comment: speed in program is important for me because the size of the main file is very large (4 gigabyte) when i use fclose the speed will very very reduced

Comment: i find that the fstream is very slow but FILE struct in c is very faster than c++ fstream then i use c function in writeInFile

Comment: @anonymous: the speed difference should not be noticeable if you call `sync_with_stdio(false)` [see here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/sync_with_stdio/)

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do this:

```
void writeInFile(int key , const char* charPos , std::vector<std::ofstream> & myFiles );
```

I find this makes my brain hurt less.

Comment: if i use this how can i access to the members of the vector in it by using "at" ? when i use it compiler say that ther is no operator= for this : my_files.at(remainder)=fopen(myFileName.c_str(),"a");

Comment: I'm assuming here that myFile is an ofstream.  You would open it if it wasn't open yet: myFile.at(remainder).open(convert.str());  I guess you initialize the container std::vector<std::ofstream> myFile(LIMIT*LIMIT);

Answer (score 0):

If you don't close your file in the same context where the FILE* variable is declared, you are leaking that file descriptor. At some point you are going to run out of resources and the program will crash.

Since you are using C++ from the snippet you've shown, then you would be much better off using std::vector and std::ofstream.

```
void writeInFile(int key, const char* charPos, std::vector<std::ofstream> my_files )
```

Comment: beware of the "freed in the destructor" while a using a vector which copies object around...

Comment: Yeah, I was in the middle of editing a class to do that and I thought: Hmmm I need to reference count this. So I've updated the answer to use ofstream instead. Didn't want to overcomplicate the answer, but rolling your own class to manage FILE* is a bit overcomplicated.

Answer (score 0):

As has been said, you should close the file in the scope it is opened. This is the default behavior for C++ streams.

However it does not mean that you should open/close for each word you add! The files you write to should be kept open as long as you have things to add to them (beware there is a limit in the number of file descriptors an OS can handle).

Therefore, you should have:

1. Open all destination files (*)
2. For each line, select the appropriate file in a table/map and write into it
3. Close all destination files

(*) As said, you might run into a hard limit, in this case there is not much you can do, caching is unlikely to be effective if your hash function is worth anything. A possibility would be to make several runs over the big file and saving only a portion of the hashes at each run (say run 1: hashes in [0-9], run 2: hashes in [10-19], ...).

The fundamental type `FILE*` or `ofstream` that you use is of little importance, both have comparable speed (correctly tuned).